# How to use the -stats_period parameter together with FFMPEG -progress?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using **-pregress** to get the current frame that is being processed, leaving it in a .txt file, but I would like to use **-stats_period** to control the time that the file is updated. However, when adding -stats_period to the script, it presents an error message:

> Unrecognized option 'stats_period'. Error splitting the argument list:
> Option not found

And I couldn't find any examples of use, neither in the forums, nor in the ffmpeg documentation.

Comment: I think you meant `-progress` rather than `-pregress`?

Answer (score 2):

I added this on 23 Dec 2020. So, it's not in any release yet. Get a git/nightly/snapshot build from http://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html

Usage is trivial. Add `-stats_period 2.5` for a 2.5 second update interval.

Comment: it is not trivial, I added it like this in the documentation. But when adding the parameter -stats_period 2.5 the error is displayed.

>>Unrecognized option 'stats_period'.
>>Error splitting the argument list: Option not found

Comment: Your build isn't recent enough, as mentioned.

Comment: I am using the latest version of the compilation available for Windows.

Comment: ffmpeg version 4.3.1-2021-01-01-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers

  built with gcc 10.2.0 (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project)

Comment: sorry, just now I understand that it is not really available in the windows compilation that you make available. Could you tell me if there is a forecast to be added in the next review?

Comment: It is the git build only, as I mentioned.

Comment: To clarify: the period is clock time, not input file time, right? i.e. `-stats_period 10` means "output progress every 10 seconds", not "output progress after processing every 10 seconds of the input".

Comment: @OverlookMotel Correct.